# org.springframework.ldap.repository.LdapRepository missing in spring-ldap 2.3.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring-ldap

I have problem finding this class (org.springframework.ldap.repository.LdapRepository) in spring-ldap 2.3.0.RELEASE.  Was it deprecated?  Or it was moved to another jar?

Answer (score 1):

I found it.  It moved to spring-data ldap.  Sorry, I couldn't find anything in the document about this class migration.